# How to get corresponding build artifacts of a job in jenkins ?

Tags: build, hudson, jenkins, command-line-interface, jobs

I create Jenkins jobs using **hudson.cli.CLI jar**. I have selected **"Archive the artifacts"** option in the **"Post-build steps"** section. It archives the artifacts on each succesfull build. I am using **jenkins remote access api** `http://localhost:8080/job/job_name/api/json` to get details about **jobs**. and `http://localhost:8080/job/job_name/job_number/api/json` to get details about **builds**.

When I delete a build corresponding archived artifacts are not deleted. I'd like to make sure that they are deleted.

When I use jenkins remote access api `http://localhost:8080/job/[job_name]/[job_number]/api/json` for a build, it returns json data which contains **all** previously archived artifacts (other successful builds artifacts) with this (running build) build artifact. How do I get related artifact of a build (a successful build should return its artifact, not all previous successfull artifacts). Any suggestions or ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you do not clean your workspace between the builds and archive all the artifacts that are found there, including those from previous builds.

Answer (score 5):

A build with no archived artifacts will have this json output:

```
"artifacts":[]
```

A build with archived artifacts will have this kind of json output:

```
"artifacts":[{"displayPath":"output","fileName":"output","relativePath":"output"}]
```

This artifact could be seen at `http://localhost:8080/job/[job_name]/[job_number]/artifact/`